# Google Maps Javascript API v3 rendering combined TravelModes in one route

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to render a route that consists of both DRIVING and TRANSIT TravelMode parts (Legs).

I get the results separately, but I am unable to render them all together onto the map. As I render them one after another, the next render wipes the previously rendered route off the map. 
Seems that a request can only be made with one set of parameters, and that the method to make just one route with waypoints doesn't accept legs with different TravelModes.

Does anyone have ideas on how to either manipulate the response set by adding into DirectionsRoute object the route[] or leg[] arrays from other results, or to prevent the renderer to start all over at the next call?

Or even another approach?

Answer (score 0):

A DirectionsRenderer may only draw a single route at a time.

When you want to draw multiple routes(results) you must use separate DirectionsRenderer-instances for each result.

Comment: Yess! Multiple DirectionsRenderer instances can use the one and same map by using .setMap(themap). But I must correct you, I only need to start one instance for each TravelMode. With two instances I could  render a TRANSIT route, then a DRIVING route and again a TRANSIT route. Both transit routes are preserved on the map. - Thanks Doc!